# How to obtain different combinations in Java

Tags: java, string, api, combinations

If I have a string, say "ABCDE," what's the best way to get combinations of two? Is there an API for such a task?

i.e.

1. "AB"
2. "AC"
3. "AD"
4. "AE"
5. "BC"
6. "BD"
7. "BE"
8. "CD"
9. "CE"
10. "DE"

Comment: As far as I know, there is no in-built API for that. You have to write your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static List<String> getCombinations(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int len = input == null ? 0 : input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            String combination = String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))
                    + input.charAt(j);
            System.out.println("adding: " + combination);
            result.add(combination);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

generates for `getCombinations("ABCDE");`

```
adding: AB
adding: AC
adding: AD
adding: AE
adding: BC
adding: BD
adding: BE
adding: CD
adding: CE
adding: DE
```

Answer (score 1):

No API.  The best source to read is Knuth "The Art of Computer Programming Vol 1" or something like this:

http://webhome.csc.uvic.ca/~haron/CoolCocoon.pdf

Answer (score 0):

i+1pseudocode:

```
    String alphabet = "ABCDE";
    for( int i = 0; i < alphabet.getLength(); i++){
     for( int j = alphabet.getLength(); j > i; j--){
       System.out.println( alphabet.substring(i, i+1) + alphabet.substring(j, j+1) );
     }
    }
```

If you need more combinations like:
BA
CA 
and so on then because there are only 2 letters you can switch the position of both of them and append the result of this process to the generated pairs. If you need combinations of three and so on then take a look on permutation algorithms.